# Is there a way in PHP to strip whitespace from JSON without using ob_gzhandler?

Tags: php, json, compression, gzip, file-get-contents

I'm grabbing some JSON data using file_get_contents and I need to compress it so I can add it as a data attribute on an HTML element in my page. Basically I just need to strip out line breaks, extra spaces or tabs. Everybody seems to suggest using ob_gzhandler. But I can't do that - I don't have control over the modules that are enabled on our production environment. Can anybody suggest a PHP snippet that'll do what I want without ob_gzhandler?

Comment: It may be helpful to list the modules that ARE available then, as the possible solutions may also depend on certain modules.

Comment: Is there any chance you would be willing to rename the title of your question to something like the following:  Is there a way in PHP to strip whitespace from JSON?

Comment: Sure, I've changed it to something more like your suggestion.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want the data written as JSON you could do a simple:

```
echo json_encode(json_decode($data));
```

This will strip all whitespaces

Comment: Not working if you've got utf8 characters in the response.

Comment: To prevent breaking utf8: `json_encode(json_decode($data), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` @RafałMnich

Comment: To prevent escaping unicode and slashes too `json_encode(json_decode($data), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`